# How can command list display be categorised within a Click chained group?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm starting a CLI pipe-type application project which will eventually have a rather large collection of commands (which will be further extensible with plug-in). As a result, I would like to categorise them in the `--help` text:

Here is how it looks now:

```
Usage: my_pipe [OPTIONS] COMMAND1 [ARGS]... [COMMAND2 [ARGS]...]...

Options:
  --help         Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  another_filter     help about that filter
  another_generator  help about that generator
  another_sink       help about that sink
  some_filter        help about this filter
  some_generator     help about this generator
  some_sink          help about this sink
```

This is more or less how I would like it to look:

```
Usage: my_pipe [OPTIONS] COMMAND1 [ARGS]... [COMMAND2 [ARGS]...]...

Options:
  --help         Show this message and exit.

Commands:

  Generators:
     some_generator     help about this generator
     another_generator  help about that generator

  Filters:
     some_filter        help about this filter
     another_filter     help about that filter

  Sinks:
     some_sink          help about this sink
     another_sink       help about that sink
```

How can this be achieved? Note that apart from the look of `--help`, I'm happy with the flat logical command organisation. Also, sub-groups are not an option as they are not allowed inside a `chain=True` group.

Comment: Try docopt: https://github.com/docopt/docopt

It basically lets you write the help text, just like you already have, in the module's docstring and creates an argument parser for you.

Comment: @magarnicle: well the plan is to have new command added with plug-in, so I don't think docopt is the good way to go in this instance. Unless it is? In which case I'd be glad to hear about it.

Comment: It's probably not impossible, but my first guess is that the plugins would have to modify the docstring or whatever docopt does. Both seem to defeat the purpose of docopt, which is to not have to use code to parse args.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inherit from `click.Group` you can add a bit of code to group the commands and then show those groups in the help.

#### Custom Class

```py
class GroupedGroup(click.Group):

    def command(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Gather the command help groups"""
        help_group = kwargs.pop('group', None)
        decorator = super(GroupedGroup, self).command(*args, **kwargs)

        def wrapper(f):
            cmd = decorator(f)
            cmd.help_group = help_group
            return cmd

        return wrapper

    def format_commands(self, ctx, formatter):
        # Modified fom the base class method

        commands = []
        for subcommand in self.list_commands(ctx):
            cmd = self.get_command(ctx, subcommand)
            if not (cmd is None or cmd.hidden):
                commands.append((subcommand, cmd))

        if commands:
            longest = max(len(cmd[0]) for cmd in commands)
            # allow for 3 times the default spacing
            limit = formatter.width - 6 - longest

            groups = {}
            for subcommand, cmd in commands:
                help_str = cmd.get_short_help_str(limit)
                subcommand += ' ' * (longest - len(subcommand))
                groups.setdefault(
                    cmd.help_group, []).append((subcommand, help_str))

            with formatter.section('Commands'):
                for group_name, rows in groups.items():
                    with formatter.section(group_name):
                        formatter.write_dl(rows)
```

#### Using the Custom Class

To make use of the custom class, use the `cls` parameter to pass the class to the `click.group()` decorator.

```py
@click.group(cls=GroupedGroup)
def cli():
    """My awesome cli"""
```

Then for each command mark the help group for the command to be included in like:

```py
@cli.command(group='A Help Group')
def command():
    """This is a command"""
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.group()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Group` object but allows this behavior to be overridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Group` in our own class and override desired methods.

In this case we override the `click.Group.command()` decorator to gather up the desired help group for each command.  Then we override the `click.Group.format_commands()` method to use those groups when constructing the help.

#### Test Code

```py
import click

@click.group(cls=GroupedGroup)
def cli():
    """My awesome cli"""

@cli.command(group='Generators')
def some_generator():
    """This is Some Generator"""

@cli.command(group='Generators')
def another_generator():
    """This is Another Generator"""

@cli.command(group='Filters')
def some_filter():
    """This is Some Filter"""

@cli.command(group='Filters')
def another_filter():
    """This is Another Filter"""

cli()
```

#### Results

```plaintext
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  My awesome cli

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:

  Filters:
    another-filter     This is Another Filter
    some-filter        This is Some Filter

  Generators:
    another-generator  This is Another Generator
    some-generator     This is Some Generator
```

Comment: Outstanding writeup! This works well and is exactly what I was looking for.